# Youtube embedded Iframe api cancels all other events

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm having a problem with the youtube embedded player breaking the other event listeners on my page.I'm spefically using the Iframe API because I need an html5 player, and generally the functionality that I want is for it to be embedded into a draggable dialogue box.

```
/*DRAGGING*****************************************/                
                    //get offset and set dragging
                    header.onmousedown = preDrag; 
                    document.onmouseup = function(e){
                        dragging = false; 
                    }; 
                    //drag
                    document.onmousemove = drag; 
                    ytplayer.onmousemove =  drag; 
                    function preDrag(){
                        offsetX = container.style.left - mouseX; 
                        offsetY = container.style.top - mouseY; 
                        //alert('left: ' + container.style.left +', top: ' + container.style.top); 
                        //alert('offsetX: ' + offsetX + ', offsetY: ' + offsetY); 
                        dragging = true; 
                    }
                    function drag(){
                        if (dragging == true){
                            container.style.top = (mouseY + offsetY)+"px";
                            container.style.left = (mouseX + offsetX)+"px"; 
                        }
                    }
        }); 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text"></p>
    <div id="vidContainer">
        <div id="vidHeader"></div>
        <div id="vidPlayer"><div id='yt'></div></div>
        <div id="vidPlaylist">
            <ul id="videos">
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- <a id="add" href="#" class="btn">Add to the playlist!</a> --> 
    <script> 
        /*YOUTUBE PLAYER API*************/ 
        var player; 
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ 
            player = new YT.Player('yt', { 
                height: '390', 
                width : '640', 
                videoId: 'i3Jv9fNPjgk',
                playerVars: {
                    "html5" : 1, 
                    "enablejsapi" : 1,
                },  
                events: { 
                    'onReady' : onPlayerReady, 
                    'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange, 
                } 
            }); 
        } 

        function onPlayerReady(event){
            event.target.playVideo(); 
        }           

        function onPlayerStateChange(event){

        }

        function stopVideo(){
            player.stopVideo(); 
        }
        function someFunc(){
            alert('oh hey the first time!!!'); 
        }
        /*******************************/
    </script>
</body>
```

This code will allow for the user to click on the header (above the video) and drag it around, which moves the whole container. The problem is that if the user moves the mouse quickly there is a possibility that the mouse will move into the region occupied by the youtube video, which stops the dragging function. That means that `document.onmousemove` is not getting activated, hence why I think that the youtube player is cancelling the document events.

I've tried 2 solutions to this:

1. create a wrapper div for the youtube player and attach event listeners to that: This was the `ytplayer.onmousemove = drag` and it completely fails.
2. attach event listeners to the youtube video player object in

   `events: { "onmouseover": "someFunc" }`

   but that also fails.

I'm kind of out of ideas and I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the events will not be propagated by the iframe to the application due to browser security, so this works as expected. Have you tried detecting when the user enters/exits the iframe to adjust behavior of your app?